# How to get the decryption method working to return the encrypted string back to the original?

Tags: java, string, encryption

I have been instructed to write a program which should encrypt a given string by input from the user and generate a random encryption character for each letter that has been input while ensuring that the same character appearing more than once in the original is replaced by the same character in the coded string.

I must also ensure that no two characters in the original are coded as the same character in the coded string, in order to enable successful decryption.

However, the decryption gives me back a completely different string to what I had in the first place. Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Caesar {
public static final int ALPHASIZE = 26;             // upper case alphabets
public static final char[] alpha = {'A','B','C','D',
    'E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P',
    'Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};


protected char[] encrypt = new char [ALPHASIZE];    // encryption array
protected char[] decrypt = new char [ALPHASIZE];    // decryption array

// constructor that initializes the encryption and decryption arrays

Random randomGen = new Random();

public Caesar() {

int random = randomGen.nextInt(ALPHASIZE);

{
    for(int i=0; i< ALPHASIZE; i++)
        encrypt[i]=alpha[(i+random)%ALPHASIZE]; 

    for(int i=0; i< ALPHASIZE; i++)
        decrypt[encrypt[i]- 'A']=alpha[i];   
}
}

// encryption method
public String encrypt(String secret)
{
    char[] mess = secret.toCharArray();     // the message array
    for(int i=0; i<mess.length; i++)        // encryption loop
        if(Character.isUpperCase(mess[i]))  // a letter to change
            mess[i]=encrypt [mess[i]-'A'];  // use letter as index
        else  if(Character.isLowerCase(mess[i]))  // a letter to change
            mess[i]=(new String(""+encrypt [mess[i]-'a'])).toLowerCase().charAt(0);  // use letter as index
    return new String (mess);
}

// decryption method
public String decrypt (String secret)
{
    char[] mess = secret.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0; i<mess.length; i++)
        if (Character.isUpperCase(mess[i]))
            mess[i]=decrypt[mess[i]-'A'];
         else  if(Character.isLowerCase(mess[i]))  // a letter to change
            mess[i]=(new String(""+decrypt [mess[i]-'a'])).toLowerCase().charAt(0);  // use letter as index
    return new String (mess);

}
}

Test Class
public class CaesarTryOut {


public static void main(String[] args) {


System.out.println("Please enter your message:");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String c = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println();

System.out.println("You entered the following message:");
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println();

Caesar cipher = new Caesar();

String code = c;



String secretEncrypt = cipher.encrypt(c);
System.out.println("Your string has been encrypted to:");
System.out.println(secretEncrypt);
System.out.println();



String secretDecrypt = cipher.decrypt(c);
System.out.println("Your message has been decrypted to:");
System.out.println(secretDecrypt);
System.out.println();

}
}
```

Comment: Debug by examining entire contents of both the `encrypt` and `decrypt` arrays to see if they are what you expect.

Comment: This won't fix the problem, but if `ch` is a `char`, `Character.toLowerCase(ch)` returns the lower-case version of the character.  No need to go through `String`s to do this conversion.

Comment: Could you post the code that tests the class?  The code you've posted seems OK.

Comment: I have tried going through both arrays with the debugger, the decrypt one is blank however the encrypt one works by moving along x places based on the random number generated I just don't know how to reverse that to decrypt it back to the original.

Comment: @ajb My test class has been added to my original post

Comment: What string are you decrypting when you call `cipher.decrypt`?

Comment: @ajb the one which the user enters from the scanner

Comment: So then how do you test whether decrypting the encrypted string returns the original string?  Run the program twice?

Comment: No, it does it in the one run like it will tell me what the original string put in was, what it was encrypted to and then supposedly decrypts in back to the original.

Comment: But you said `cipher.decrypt` decrypts the string the user enters via Scanner.  (Which is correct.)  So where does it decrypt the encrypted string?

Comment: Sorry, in the method 'public string decrypt'

Comment: No, the `decrypt` method decrypts whatever you pass to it as a parameter when you call the method.  And you're not calling it with the encrypted string.  You're calling it with the string that the user entered (as you said).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are decrypting the string that user gave input, in order to decrypt the message you have to pass the parameter of the encrypted string that you got.

String secretDecrypt = cipher.decrypt(secretEncrypt);